# Can't get Font Awesome to show up

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

so this is a simple question, I would just like for my fa to show up.. I've uploaded the FA CSS, it's in the head tag, so I don't know what's missing

This is the code :

```css
#draginfo {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:70px;
    right:193px;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    background-size:auto;
    background:#BDBDBD;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

#draginfo i{
display:inline-block;
margin-top:0;
margin-left:-3px;
height:10px;
width:10px;
padding:10px;
color:#fff;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:15px;
line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="draginfo">
<i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</body>
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Does it work with that link? https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: A dropbox download link is not usable inside a `href` attribute. Either provide a link to a cdn (from bootstrap) or upload the file to your server and link it relatively to the html linking it.

Comment: inside `class"fa fa-info"` missed `=`

Comment: Please first make sure your code syntax is correct before putting in the question. `<i class"fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i>` is missing the `=` on the class attribute.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry about that I hadn't noticed it.. Thank you for the replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the color to white and put it on a white background.
See below:

```css
#draginfo {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 70px;
  right: 193px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-size: auto;
  background: #BDBDBD;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#draginfo i {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: -3px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="draginfo">
      <i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code is exactly the same as yours, just changing the `color` to red.

Answer (score 0):

You miss `;` after "color" - `color:#fff`

and `=` after "class" - `class"fa fa-info"`

and set wrong cdn for FA style. for ex. use `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css`

Comment: Thank you, I've edited this, but it still doesn't show up? The weird thing is I have other fa icons and they're working